# Get related table data in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i have a rating table.

[image]

The model relationship: 
Rating is belongs to user & User has many rating.

The scenario is users have a profile page. It will display all ratings and users information who rate for the particular user.

I using `$ratings= Rating::where('user_id',$user->id)->get();`
But this only return rating information which belong to the user. No rater information.
How can i get rater information by rater_id?

Comment: Do you have a model for rater?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to build relationship in your model then you can

```
public function rater() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'rater_id'); 
}
```

now you can get the rater

```
$ratings= Rating::with('rater')->where('user_id',$user->id)->get();
```